# How to attach a function to my package's namespace after it's loaded?

Tags: r, r-package

This may seem like a weird question, but I do have a use case for it that I'm trying to figure out.

Suppose I'm writing a package and I have a function that I want to allow the user to alias to something else - the user provides the name of the function. I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve this?

```
#' @export
foo <- function() "Hello"
#' @export
addAlias <- function(x) assign(x, foo, envir = globalenv())
```

This is the behaviour I want to get - now the user can call `addAlias("bar")` and then if he calls `bar()` it'll be as if he called my function.

Obviously this is not a nice solution because it assigns to the global environment.  Does anyone have feedback on what would be the best way to do this? A few methods I tried:

**1. Assigning to globalenv**

Just like I showed in the example. This seemed to work.

**2. Assigning to the package's environment**

```
addAlias <- function(x) assign(x, foo, as.environment("package:mypackage"))
```

This worked great for a while until I realized that it only works with `devtools` and not if the package is loaded properly because of locked environments

**3. Attaching a new env to the searchpath**

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  assign("aliases", new.env(), envir = parent.env(environment()))
  attach(aliases)
  invisible()
}

addAlias <- function(x) assign(x, foo, aliases)
```

This I don't like because of the use of `attach`.  Is it warranted in this case?  When would I `detach`?

**4. Expose a separate named environment**

```
#' @export
#' @keywords internal
aliases <- new.env()

addAlias <- function(x) assign(x, foo, aliases)
```

This works, but instead of being able to call `bar()`, the user needs to call `alises$bar()` or `mypackage::aliases$bar()`.  I don't like that, but it was an interesting experiment. I also don't know if it's ok to export a variable like that?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think a more appropriate way is to use [closure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures).

```
#' @export
foo <- function() "Hello"
#' @export
getfoo <- function() {
    function(){
        # do anything, including running foo()
        foo()
    }
}
```

With this, you can do

```
> bar <- getfoo()
> bar()
[1] "Hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I don't think this answers the main question?

Comment: I think this is an alternative solution to achieve what you wanna do. I believe that assigning variables to a locked environment is not an efficient way for this purpose.

Comment: So to make sure I understand - with this approach, you're suggesting the user does the assignment to a variable, rather than doing it in the code, right?  I want to the user to pass in a vector of strings and assign each of them to my function. I don't see how to do that with this code?

Comment: Can you just let users choose how many instances do they want to get? For example, one could do `bars <- replicate(100, getfoo()); bars[[1]]()`

Comment: No that wouldn't work for my need :) I need to have the user call a function with a vector of strings, and inside the function it would create bindings to those strings that the user can call later. But that's not the return value, I'm returning something else.